# Heroku availability zone

Tags: heroku

I plan on having a Heroku app communicating with a database server made with Amazon AWS. I am aware that Heroku is built on AWS; is it possible to set the availability zone of my Heroku app to be the same as my database server, so that queries can be made as fast as possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think this is currently possible. I believe Heroku have infrastructure in different zones in order to failover if necessary.

There some useful information here: [Heroku: Is Heroku dependent on a single Amazon Availability Zone?](http://www.quora.com/Heroku/Is-Heroku-dependent-on-a-single-Amazon-Availability-Zone)

You could create the database server in the same zone as Heroku, but you would run into the same problem if they failover.